# Mesh simplification with regard to vertex colors

Tags: render, mesh, simplification

I have a mesh (points, triangles and color per vertex) The point cloud is dense enough so this texture representation is good. now I would like to simpify the mesh without distroying the render quality (and without moving to texture mapping)

Ideas? So far I've removed vertexes based on some huristic (color and normal similarity to neighbors) and then trying to make a triangulation (ball pivot) with meshlab. That's working ok.

any better ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

High quality mesh simplification is unfortunately not an easy task and you will need a good algorithm to decide which vertices can be removed without decreasing quality too much.

Some established algorithms exist already and are published online, e.g.:

- "New Quadric Metric for Simplifying Meshes with Appearance
  Attributes" of Hugues Hoppe
- "Simplifying Surfaces with Color and Texture using Quadric Error Metrics" of Michael Garland et al.